# How to store multiple value/objects in azure key vault

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I want to deploy more than 100 webapps in one azure pipeline. I want to put these webapp name in azure key vault. But there has only one value can be stored in one variable. Is there any way to put multiple value or object in one variable in azure key vault.

```
    parameters:
    - name: apps
      type: object
      default:
        - JustGoTestAgain
        - justgotesttwo
        - and so on
    
    steps:
    - ${{ each app in parameters.apps}}:
      - task: AzureWebApp@1
        displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy ${{ app }}'
        continueOnError: true
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: '$(Parameters.connectedServiceName)'
          appType: webApp
          ResourceGroupName: $(group)
          appName: ${{ app }}
          package: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/**/*.zip'
```

I have also put multiple value using comma in azure secret vault. Is this the right way to store multiple value? I ran pipeline but it completes with this warning

> ##[error]Error: Failed to fetch App Service '***' publishing credentials. Error: The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/***' under
> resource group '***' was not found. For more details please go to
> https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix (CODE: 404)

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to store a bunch of variables in a single object in Key Vault, I recommend that you use a JSON object with a bunch of key/value pairs.  That way you can deserialize it quickly.